# Создание массива структур

Tags: c, массивы, структуры

У меня есть несколько заданий. Первое: создать структуру с несколькими полями. Вот она:

```
struct docEdit 
{
    char text[20];
    int StrNum;
};
```

А вот второе я не очень понял. " Создать структуру (struct) Стек / Очередь, она будет включать в себя массив структур с данными и реализовать основные функции стека/очереди(pop,push,empty,size).
! реализовать стек / очередь на основе статического массива. Я не понимаю, что значит "она будет включать в себя массив структур с данными". Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то сможет объяснить или наведёт пример.

Comment: Так нужен С или С++?

Comment: Желательно си, так как, насколько я знаю, в с++ немного по-другому.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это значит, что Вам нужно создать ещё одну структуру, которая будет хранить в себе массив элементов типа `docEdit`. Ну и функции для работы с этой структурой. Вот заготовка для стека:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 64
#define TEXT_SIZE 20

struct docEdit 
{
    char text[TEXT_SIZE];
    int StrNum;
};

struct Stack
{
    docEdit items[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
    int top; // Индекс свободной вершины стека
};

// Функция инициализации стека
void StackInit(struct Stack* st);

// Функция добавления элемента в стек
void StackPush(struct Stack* st, struct docEdit de);

// Функция извлечения из стека
void StackPop(struct Stack* st);

// Функция проверки на пустоту стека
int StackIsEmpty(struct Stack* st);

// Функция проверки на максимальную заполненность стека
int StackIsFull(struct Stack* st);

// Функция, которая возвращает количество элементов в стеке
int StackSize(struct Stack* st);

// Функция, которая возвращает указатель на элемент вершины стека для доступа к нему
docEdit* StackTop(struct Stack* st);
```

Реализацию функций оставляю на Вас:)

Answer (score -1):

Непонятно из того, что написано, но наверняка вам нужно что-то вроде этого

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <queue> 
using namespace std; 
  
struct docEdit 
{
    char text[20];
    int StrNum;
};

int main() 
{ 
    queue<docEdit*> myqueue; 

    docEdit first = new docEdit(); 
    first->StrNum = 1;
    myqueue.push(&first);

    docEdit second = new docEdit(); 
    first->StrNum = 2;
    myqueue.push(&second);

    while (!myqueue.empty()) { 
        cout << ' ' << myqueue.front()->StrNum; 
        delete myqueue.front();
        myqueue.pop(); 
    } 
}
```

И то же самое для стека